# What's the frequency for onSensorChanged in android?

Tags: android, motion

Frequency is always highest as they were registered.
But question is : synchronous or not?

If the gyro sensor proivdes 200HZ at most, accel sensor provides 50HZ at most in my phone,
So the onSensorChanged function provides gyro data 4 times then accel data 1 time?

I just found if I call for gyro data 50Hz and accel data 20 Hz,
there would always be same gyro data 2 by 2.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Part1:

```
public void initListeners(){
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

Part 2:

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

```
    switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        // copy new accelerometer data into accel array and calculate orientation
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, accel, 0, 3);
        calculateAccMagOrientation();
        ...
        }
        break;

    case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
        // process gyro data
        gyroFunction(event);
        break;

    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        // copy new magnetometer data into magnet array
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, magnet, 0, 3);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

the default data delay (SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) is specified when the registerListener() method is invoked. The data delay (or sampling rate) controls the interval at which sensor events are sent to your application via the onSensorChanged() callback method. The default data delay is suitable for monitoring typical screen orientation changes and uses a delay of 200,000 microseconds. You can specify other data delays, such as SENSOR_DELAY_GAME (20,000 microsecond delay), SENSOR_DELAY_UI (60,000 microsecond delay), or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (0 microsecond delay). As of Android 3.0 (API Level 11) you can also specify the delay as an absolute value (in microseconds).
You can Refer [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor) For More Information!!!